# aws-sdk-ruby AWS::Record::Base records sharing the same domain

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

We are using the aws-sdk for ruby, specifically AWS::Record::Base.

For various reasons we need to put records of various objects within the same domain in sdb.

The approach we thought we'd use here would be to add an attribute to each object that contains the object name and then include that in the where clause of finder methods when obtaining objects from sdb.

My questions to readers are:

1. what are your thoughts on this approach?
2. how would this be best implemented tidily? How is it best to add a default attribute included in an object without defining it explicitly in each model? Is overriding find or where in the finder methods sufficient to ensure that obtaining objects from sdb includes the clauses considering the new default attribute?

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. It really depends on your problem, but I find it slightly distasteful. Variant records are fine and dandy, but when you start out with apples and dinosaurs and they have no common attributes, this approach has no benefit that I know of [aside from conserving your (seemingly pointless) quota of 250 SimpleDB domains].  If your records have *something* in common, then I can see where this approach might be useful, but someone scarred like me by legacy systems with variant records in Btrieve (achieved through C unions) has a hardwired antipathy toward this approach.
2. The cleanest approach I can think of is to have your models share a common parent through inheritance.  The parent could then know of the child types, and implement the query appropriately.  However, this design is definitely not [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).